# Unable restrict the click event listener outside region of LeftNavButton and RightNavButton?

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am created one sample alloy app in appcelerator studio.
When I click on outside button(image) also event is performed.
How to restrict the click event, If I perform event outside the LeftNavButton or RightNavButton.
Can one help me out.

**signIn.js**:

```
$.signInWin.addEventListener('open', function() {

        Ti.API.info('signInWin open');

        var titleLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text: 'Log In', width: Ti.UI.SIZE});
        $.signInWin.setTitleControl(titleLabel);

        var leftButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
            backgroundImage : '/left_arrow.png'
        });
        $.signInWin.setLeftNavButton(leftButton);

        var rightButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
            backgroundImage : '/right_arrow.png'
        });
        $.signInWin.setRightNavButton(rightButton);

        leftButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            Ti.API.info(' event performed on left button');

        });

        rightButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            Ti.API.info(' event performed on right button');

        });
});
```

**signIn.tss:**

```
"#signInWin":{
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',

}
"#signInNav":{
    backgroundColor: '#00a2f7',

}
```

**signIn.xml:**

```
<Alloy>
    <NavigationWindow id="signInNav" platform="ios">
        <Window id="signInWin">

        </Window> 
    </NavigationWindow>
</Alloy>
```

**Sample Screen View**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The clickable area of a rightNavButton/leftNavButton extends the button itself by a few pixels. That is a native behavior of iOS. To resolve this, you could wrap the button inside a `Ti.UI.View` which has a fixed `height`. That should resolve your problem pretty easy!